# How to say X to the power of Y?

Tags: usage

How does one say X to the power of Y?　　(i.e. X^Y)

XのY乗{じょう} ?

Comment: Exactly. As a verb you can say 2・3・4乗{じょう}する

Comment: if its something like 10^-5 is it okay to say 「10のマイナス5乗」？